# Cppcheck error: size is not a multiple of the underlying type's size

Tags: c, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I have this line in a C program:

```
double** out = malloc(3 * sizeof(double*));
```

My program works, but in my editor, `cppcheck` reports this error:

> The allocated size 12 is not a multiple of the underlying type's size.

What does it mean? Is there really a possible error here?

## EDIT 2018-05-02

This warning has disappeared after the new update of CPPcheck.

Comment: It probably means that the "underlying type" is `double` and its size is probably 8 bytes so the allocated 12 bytes for the three pointers is not a multiple of 8. I don't think there is an error here.

Comment: I do not get such results from cppcheck

Comment: @ChristianGibbons If you are running on a 64-bit machine, the size of pointers is also 8 bytes so the allocated size will be 24.

Comment: @s7amuser Good point.

Comment: "The allocated size 12 is not a multiple of the underlying type's size." simply means the allocation will include a few padding bytes.  Not an error - unless the issue is elsewhere in unposted code.

Comment: Okay, I tried making my own example substituting a 16-byte `struct` for `double` so that I could could allocate 24 bytes while the datatype was 16 bytes to re-create the mismatch, and I am still not getting anything from cppcheck.

Comment: Unrelated, but consider writing `malloc(3 * sizeof *out);` instead. It's more robust if you happen to change types later. (And IMHO it has better readability as well ...)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for your comments. Please what do you mean by "change types later"? A cast?

Comment: No, just a change in the code. You don't want `double*` any more but `struct myfancyrefcontainer` instead. With the expression-syntax of `sizeof` in use, you can't forget to change the type there as well.

Comment: The warning is not here anymore with the new update of CPPcheck.

Comment: Sounds like a false positive. Still, you probably meant to allocate a 2D array, in which case the code should be corrected to `double (*out)[n] = malloc( sizeof(double[3][n]) );`.

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a false positive.

It was introduced in Cppcheck 1.56 and was fixed in version 1.72.